# Imagen fondo en canvas

Tags: c#, unity

Tengo un canvas al que he añadido un raw image.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que desde código le asigne una imagen de fondo?

Tengo este código que lee unas carpetas y busca dónde está la imagen.

```
private void LoadBgImage() {
        string RuteBackground = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/ImgBackground";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(RuteBackground);
        string background = files.FirstOrDefault(s => s.EndsWith(".jpg") || s.EndsWith(".png"));

    }
```

en background se me guarda la ruta de la imagen.

¿Cómo la asigno al raw image del canvas?

Comment: se trata de un desarrollo web ? o es xaml

Comment: se trata de Unity ,c#

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener la imagen desde una ruta dada de la siguiente forma:

```
Sprite img = Resources.Load<Sprite>(background);
```

donde **background** es la ruta de la imagen de tu ejemplo.
Luego puedes agregar la imagen a tu control.

```
imagen.sprite = img
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ello puedes crear un panel que ocupe todo el canvas, Y luego desde el script creas una variable asi:

```
Public Image imagenDeFondo;
```

Luego accedes a la propiedad sprite del panel y le asignas tu imagen.

```
imagenDeFondo.sprite = tuImagen;
```

Espero haber ayudado, Cualquier cosa comenta.